# Ajax fires a lot of times on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin jrating. https://github.com/alpixel/jRating .

HTML

```
<button class="btn">ADD</button>


<div id="doc"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
    $('#doc').append('aaa<div class="rating" id="0_5"></div>');
    $('.rating').jRating();
});
$('.rating').jRating();
```

when i dynamically add new divs to doc. Rating doesn't show up if i dont use `$('.rating').jRating();` in click function.

**Problem :** when i dynamically append four divs and click on the first appended div ajax is firing 4 times. This goes on 4 all other elements. like when click on 3rd appended div 3 time , 2nd 2 times. Don't know why this is happening

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFWXG/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `$('.rating').jRating();` inside the click handler, you are again and again initializing the plugin for all the `rating` elements present in the page instead of initializing only for the new element

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
   $('aaa<div class="rating" id="0_5"></div>').appendTo('#doc').jRating();    
});
```